# Name for methods of smoothely approximating absolute value

Tags: reference-request, absolute-value, regression

The absolute value function $x \mapsto |x|$ is frequently used as a loss function in regression methods in place of the square function $x \mapsto x^2$ because it is less sensitive to outliers. Unfortunately it is not differentiable, so for applying e.g. Newton methods it is often approximated by a "smoothed version"

$$ x \mapsto \sqrt{x^2 + \epsilon }$$

for some small $\epsilon >0$.

> Does this approximation have a name? Is there a known person who first introduced it?

Comment: There is such a thing as a "mollified loss function", but it's used for a slightly different smoothing technique.

Comment: @kimchilover Thank you for the comment. In the mean time I also found the [Huber loss function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huber_loss) but that is also slightly different.